# How many menus can we choose?

Tags: combinatorics

Six students go to a restaurant, they can choose between 4 meals (each of them). How many orders are possible? My answer was $4^6$, but the given one is $84$.
What is the problem?

Comment: The difference is whether we care (*for example from the student's perspective*) who gets what meal which has $4^6$ possibilities... or if we are only caring (*for example from the cook's perspective*) how many of what type of meal is made but not caring who gets what which has $\binom{6+4-1}{4-1}=84$ possibilities.  The question is ambiguous which of these is intended.

Comment: Ok, so the answer is the cook´s perspective, right? Instead of doing $4^6$ you must do $9\choose 3$